# Unable to build docker image in .Net core

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-build

Net 5 application. I am trying to build docker image in my local system. I have .Net project with multi layers. Below is my project structure

src

```
 BusinessModel
 Facade
 Geography
 Repository
 Saga
 Dockerfile
 Geography.sln
```

Below is my Dockerfile

```sh
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY Geography/*.csproj  ./Geography/
COPY Repository/*.csproj ./Repository/
COPY BusinessModel/*.csproj ./BusinessModel
COPY Facade/*.csproj ./Facade/
COPY Saga/*.csproj ./Saga/



RUN dotnet restore "Geography/Geography.csproj"
COPY . .

RUN dotnet build "Geography/Geography.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Geography/Geography.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Geography.dll"]
```

When I run the above dockerfile I get below error
In the above code line copy . . is giving error. failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: cannot copy to non-directory: BusinessModel

I am not able to figure it out the issue. Can someone help me in this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There should be more descriptive message of what exact directory doesn't exists, please add it to the question

Comment: it looks like some of the required files missing where you run the dockerfile. Dockerfile should be at the same directory with your csproj etc. files. if you are using cmd, be sure you are calling dockerfile on correct path.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I am getting below error message- failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: cannot copy to non-directory: BusinessModel